# Why does pressing "Enter" close the batch file only on the first press?

Tags: batch-file, crash, enter

So I've noticed that when I start my batch file and come to a user prompt, if "Enter" is the first key pressed, the file will terminate.  If "Enter" is pressed on the second or subsequent try, the file behaves normally (and follows the goto back to the menu again).  Why does this happen and/or how can I prevent it from happening?  I tried using pause and timeout but spamming enter will still crash it.

To explain using the code below, if A is pressed, we goto :hello.  Else we return to :menu.  This works for any key except enter.  If you hit enter you crash.  But if you hit something else, reload menu, then enter reloads as well.

Example code below:

```
@echo off

:menu
echo A: Hello
set /p _input=Choice? 
if %_input%==A goto hello
goto menu

:hello
echo Hello!
pause
exit
```

Comment: Because the IF command becomes an invalid syntax.  Put quotes around your variables. `if "%_input%"=="A" goto hello`

Comment: Great, that stopped it from crashing on first enter press.  How did the IF "become" an invalid syntax, specifically?

Comment: If you don't supply a value for `_input` (just press enter), then the variable has an empty value. So it expands to: `if ==A goto hello` which isn't valid. By quoting as @Squashman suggests, it becomes: `if ""=="A" goto hello` which is valid.

Comment: @Silver71, as Jason pointed out the variable expands to nothing. Variables are expanded before the command is executed. Since nothing was assigned to the variable the cmd processor sees it as an invalid statement because it has nothing on the left side to evaluate to the right side.

Comment: Actually, `set /P` does *not* clear any variables, it maintains the *previous value* of a variable when the user just presses _ENTER_, and it sets the `ErrorLevel` to `1` in this case; (if something is entered, `ErrorLevel` is not reset!)

Comment: It is often better to use command [choice](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732504.aspx) to take an option from a predefined list like a menu than using `set /P` where a batch user can enter anything including a string which results in exit of batch processing because of an error caused by the user input string.

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:menu
echo A: Hello
set /p _input=Choice? 
if /i "%_input%"=="" cls & goto :menu
if %_input%==A goto hello
goto menu

:hello
echo Hello!
pause
exit
```

Comment: You should explain why this works, instead of just dumping a piece of code.

Comment: Answer's are great. But for best practices, please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!